# Android plugin installation problems

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, installation, adt

I was using eclipse 3.7 helios along with android SDK r11 when, regretfully, something popped up in my mind and forced me to update my ADT Plugin and Android SDK. The idea behind that evil thought was to see my android app running on android version 4. I am not able to install the ADT plugin for eclipse after that. I tried all the tricks provided in the other answers like having the name of the folder without spaces, running the eclipse using administrator priviliges, installing a fresh copy of eclipse and installing ADT plugin on it but all in vain. No "android" is appearing in the left side list when i click on window->preferences. I am posting this question after unzipping a fresh copy of 3.7.2 and then installing software by giving the path provided in ADT plugin installation guide from android website. When i check whether its installed or not, it shows me that ADT version 20.0.1.v201207132230-403220 is installed but never loads. any ideas?

Comment: Try unzipping eclipse in the user folder (c:\users\myuser instead of program files, for example)

Comment: tried that too.. my eclipse is not in program files folder n same is the case with android sdk installation...its not on c drive (that reminds me to mention my os which is win vista 32bit)

Comment: I'm out of ideas. Next thing I'd try would be to download and extract the plugin manually to the eclipse plugins folder (restarting eclipse after extracting the plugin), or reverting to the old version if that doesn't work either. Have you tried that too?

Comment: well i tried that too.can you believe that? I was so desperate that i even tried windows restore too.all in vain.I have seen the web and its flooded with almost similar problem with ADT plugin and eclipse.There has to be some kind of log file which should atleast let the installer know what exactly has happened behind the scenes.Adding insult to my injury, I deleted the old combination and now when i try eclipse 3.7 with ADT Plugin v r11, it does not work either:) I have given admin rights to folder where my eclipse and SDK r installed to the current user and tried but no luck :/

Comment: well, that's a classic Vista-weird thing :) if nothing else works you may still try a different eclipse version or, if your processor has hardware virtualization support, try running it on a virtualbox PC or in windows 7 xp mode vista equivalent (virtual pc I think it's called.. It's not very resource efficient but actually more than one would imagine). Also in eclipse if you go to help->about->installation details->installation history you have a "revert" option that may help you..

Comment: Thank you for your time and patience elcodedocle.. I really appreciate it.. I solved the issue by installing a fresh copy of eclipse 3.7.2 and adt plugin r11. Apparently it was an issue related to the compatibility. :) ciao.

Comment: You're welcome, you can thank me trying to help some other fellow when you have the time, that's how this community rules so awesomely :)

Comment: I surely will InshaAllah.. :) :)